# Contact Form 7 is submitting when invalid on mobile device and page is reloading

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

When I try to submit a form with empty fields that are required, Contact Form 7 is submitting and page is reloading with #wpcf7-f29416-p13-o2 at the end of URL. After that validation messages are shown under particular fields. Whereas there should be a loader and page should not be reloaded. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Check your browser's console log its must be an error which stopped the ajax.

Comment: When I am submitting the form on desktop browser with mobile responsive view, it is working fine. But when I am submitting the same form on mobile this is not working correctly.

Comment: check some possibilities - https://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/

Comment: @dipmala None of them is a problem in my case.

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your theme's in header.php that there is `wp_head();` function in `<head>wp_head(); </head>` tag and `wp_footer();` before `</body>` tags ends.

Comment: Both of them are there. wp_head() in header.php and wp_footer(); in footer.php.